# Need some help with linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, inner-products

Could use some hints on solving some questions.

1. Let  be a complex  ×  matrix with rank , where  > .
   Define
   $ = (^*)^{-1} ^*$
   . Show that $H$ is a self-adjoint idempotent matrix.

What I know so far: I understand that self-adjoint means $H=H^*$ and idempotent means $HH = H$. I also know that $(A^*A)$ is hermitian. How do I proceed from here and what matrix definitions would help me?

EDIT: Managed to find idempotent matrix by multiplying the right hand side by itself. Still figuring out the hermitian.

2. Let  ∶  ⟶  be a linear operator on a finite-dimensional complex inner product space .
   Suppose that  is a normal operator. If there is some complex scalar , some unit vector , and
   some positive real number  such that
   $‖() − ‖ < $
   ,
   show that there is some eigenvalue  of  such that
   $ | − | <  $

Tried so far: Using the definition of eigenvalues and eigenvectors, I've set $$ to be an eigenvalue and $v$ to be an eigenvector of $T$, then the statement holds true because both will be $0$. But I feel like I'm missing something else and  I need some help pointing to it.

Comment: What is so difficult in computing $HH$ and $H^*$? For 2. you may assume without loss of generality that $T$ is a diagonal matrix.

Comment: @amsmath not so much of the difficulty I just wanted to understand the definitions and the fundamentals involved in proving the statement. Was going in circles just now but I just managed to prove idempotent